# How to use another theme and create a new site on redirected site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, redirect

how to create another website on redirected site?

I want to use another theme and create a new site on redirected site without remove redirection of that site. So is it possible?

Comment: _"Please give me a solution asap..."_ - no, you please learn to show some patience, _asap_. And then please go read [ask], and clarify your question, right now it is overly vague.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another website on a redirected site by using subdirectories or subdomains.
Like, if the redirected site is abc.com, you can create a new website at abc.com/new-website. The redirection will still be in place for the main domain, but the new website in the subdirectory will have its own separate theme, content, and functions.

Or you can use subdomains. So, if the redirected site is def.com, you can create a new website at new-website.def.com. Even here, similar to the previous scenario the subdomain will have its own separate theme, content and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use the same Wordpress cms or custom? First, create a sub-folder in your file manager using addon domains. Then, you can work and test the website. Let me know if you have a question.